# screenresolution, imageresolution and ppi

Tags: android, resolution, hdpi, ppi

Samsung Galaxy s6 has a screen density of 577 ppi which maps to xxhdpi - xxxhdpi

```
Screen resolution: 1440 X 2560
```

Samsung Galaxy S3 has a screen density of 306 ppi which maps to xhdpi

```
Screen resolution: 720 X 1280
```

My app with a lot of scenic images was developed against xhdpi-devices (i.e. S3)
but to have margins against the future the images has a resolution of:

```
Image resolution: 1300 X 1950
```

So - what happends with images with this resolution when put in a xxxhdpi device such as Galaxy S6? I compiled the app against an S6 and cannot see any
difference. Is this because the images are in the xhdpi-folder and s6 thanks to
this does not use the full density of 577 ppi? My theory - IF it have used the
full capacity - the images whould have been stretched out since the width is 1300 px and the screenwidht of S6 is 1440.

Greatful for answers

*EDIT: the images uses the whole screenwidth.*

Comment: The galaxy S6 uses xxxhdpi images: https://design.google.com/devices/ - so this is a x4 the base mdpi (160dpi), if you have only put images in the xhdpi folder (x2 base mdpi), then these will automatically be scaled for devices which have other dpi values. For instance if your image is in the xhdpi folder and is used on 'xxxhdpi' device then typically it will scale the image to double the dimensions, as its double the density, however the image will appear the same. Screen sizes are one thing, densities are another - If your image is set to fill the 'screen' then obviously it can distort.

Comment: @MarkKeen - so what do you recommend me to do if I want to use the app on devices with different dpis? for instance galaxy s6 (xxxhdpi) and s3. (xhdpi). The images are heavy so I have to choose just one resource folder. The res. of the images is 1300 * 1950. I only use the screen width and multipliy with 1.5 (1950 is 1.5 times 1300). So no distortion. Should I rescale the original images to a higher resolution, that is 1440 * 2560. ? The problem is that this may lead to exceed 100 MB and I dont want to use expansionfiles for the images

Comment: The images you have got are quite large in size so there is no easy solution. However the question comes to mind do you need to have all these images in the APK? A better approach would be having them on a server/cloud and downloaded on demand using libraries like picasso, and then store them on a device? Your APK size will be a lot smaller, and allows you to add images to your online library without having to update the APK release. I don't think that including 10's of megabytes of images to a APK is a good idea - let the user decide what images to download and view is a much better approach.